# ERROR 400:Your proposed upload is larger than the maximum object size specified in your Policy Document

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am getting
Error: HTTP Error: 400, `EntityTooLarge`Your proposed upload is larger than the maximum object size specified in your Policy Document.Content-length exceeds upper bound on range

while deploying next js webapp on Firebase and Cloud Functions.

solution for Error: HTTP Error: 400, `EntityTooLarge`Your proposed upload is larger than the maximum object size specified in your Policy Document.Content-length exceeds upper bound on range

Comment: Is the source folder of your functions folder (excluding the node_modules folder) larger than 100MB? If so, you are probably hitting the [single function limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#resource_limits).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985445/error-400your-proposed-upload-is-larger-than-the-maximum-object-size-specified#comment134017504_75985445) if the function is >100 MB then the upload can fail.

This error began happening for me after the recent TypeScript 5 update which pushed most of my functions over 100 MB. I was able to work around the issue by removing all `devDependencies` prior to upload by using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to edit `package.json` as part of a pre-deploy script:

```bash
jq 'del(.devDependencies)' package.json >package-noDev.json &&
  mv -f package-noDev.json package.json &&
  yarn install
```

In my experience `devDependencies` makes up about 3/4ths of the total size of the function and this change took each function well below 100 MB.

Comment: Can you please share your firebase.json

Comment: I don't use firebase.json. I directly upload my functions with [`gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your upload folder (usually 'build') does not contain files that may be making your upload size too large. In my case, I left some server downloaded data on build folder by accident, which led to this error.